# exception: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 11517 out of bounds for length 11517 in kotlin

Tags: kotlin

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) { println("Hello World!")
        var myint=15 //int datatype
        var mylong=23L//long datatype
        println("My integer ${myint}")
        println("My long integer ${mylong}")
     }
```

```
G:\kotlin_prac>kotlinc hello.kt
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: Options -Xverify:none and -noverify were deprecated in JDK 13 and will likely be removed in a future release.
exception: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 11517 out of bounds for length 11517
        at org.jetbrains.org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.readUnsignedShort(ClassReader.java:2464)
        at org.jetbrains.org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.readUTF8(ClassReader.java:2525)
        at org.jetbrains.org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.readModule(ClassReader.java:761)
        at org.jetbrains.org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.accept(ClassReader.java:646)
        at org.jetbrains.org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.accept(ClassReader.java:507)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.jvm.modules.JavaModuleInfo$Companion.read(JavaModuleInfo.kt:67)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.modules.CliJavaModuleFinder.findSystemModule(CliJavaModuleFinder.kt:44)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.modules.CliJavaModuleFinder.access$findSystemModule(CliJavaModuleFinder.kt:25)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.modules.CliJavaModuleFinder$systemModules$1.invoke(CliJavaModuleFinder.kt:37)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.modules.CliJavaModuleFinder$systemModules$1.invoke(CliJavaModuleFinder.kt:25)
        at kotlin.sequences.TransformingSequence$iterator$1.next(Sequences.kt:149)
        at kotlin.sequences.FilteringSequence$iterator$1.calcNext(Sequences.kt:109)
        at kotlin.sequences.FilteringSequence$iterator$1.hasNext(Sequences.kt:133)
        at kotlin.sequences.FlatteningSequence$iterator$1.ensureItemIterator(Sequences.kt:254)
        at kotlin.sequences.FlatteningSequence$iterator$1.hasNext(Sequences.kt:241)
        at kotlin.sequences.SequencesKt___SequencesKt.none(_Sequences.kt:1239)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.ClasspathRootsResolver.addModularRoots(ClasspathRootsResolver.kt:227)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.ClasspathRootsResolver.computeRoots(ClasspathRootsResolver.kt:124)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.ClasspathRootsResolver.convertClasspathRoots(ClasspathRootsResolver.kt:79)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinCoreEnvironment.<init>(KotlinCoreEnvironment.kt:230)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinCoreEnvironment.<init>(KotlinCoreEnvironment.kt:114)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinCoreEnvironment$Companion.createForProduction(KotlinCoreEnvironment.kt:409)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.K2JVMCompiler.createCoreEnvironment(K2JVMCompiler.kt:286)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.K2JVMCompiler.createEnvironmentWithScriptingSupport(K2JVMCompiler.kt:276)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.K2JVMCompiler.doExecute(K2JVMCompiler.kt:196)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.K2JVMCompiler.doExecute(K2JVMCompiler.kt:63)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLICompiler.execImpl(CLICompiler.java:109)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLICompiler.execImpl(CLICompiler.java:53)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLITool.exec(CLITool.kt:92)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLITool.exec(CLITool.kt:70)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLITool.exec(CLITool.kt:36)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLITool$Companion.doMainNoExit(CLITool.kt:157)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLITool$Companion.doMain(CLITool.kt:148)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.K2JVMCompiler$Companion.main(K2JVMCompiler.kt:343)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.K2JVMCompiler.main(K2JVMCompiler.kt)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:577)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.preloading.Preloader.run(Preloader.java:81)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.preloading.Preloader.main(Preloader.java:43)
```

Comment: pls tell me what happen in code

Comment: Needless to say, there's nothing wrong with the code you've posted; it compiles (and runs) fine for me. I think you'll have to post some more details: the versions of Kotlin and Java you're using, and maybe your OS and anything else that could be relevant.